# Triggered Send without adding contact on all subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to send a triggered send transactional email without adding that contact on the All Subscribers list?

Comment: Have you looked at it the TSD configuration page? There's a checkbox for that option.

Comment: Yes, but I‘m unable to save the TSD when unchecking „Add subscribers to this list“ and „Update Subscribers“ ending in the error „Choose to either add or update subscribers to the selected list“

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of this error the All Subscribers list or another one is still highlighted and you have to double-click on it until it is no longer marked. Afterwards you're able to save without that error message.

Answer (score 0):

All Subscribers is Marketing Clouds master subscription list that manages the contacts subscription status.

There's no method of using a Triggered Send without it adding the contact to All Subscribers  - Marketing Cloud needs the contact in All Subscribers to manage the send. When you configure your TSD, you can add the contact to a list, but even then the contact of a list will also add the contact to All Subscribers

This is the same functionality as when you have a contact in a data extension and you then send an email to that DE - the contact will automatically be added to All Subscribers.